# How to download multiple links to a zip file from html page

Tags: javascript, html, jszip

I am trying  to make a html page.
Now, i have a table with few rows, and in each row , i have a  links to file, which can be downloaded.

Now, I'am trying to give a button at the bottom of my page, which can be used to download all the links .
it should basically download a zip folder which has all files ( which are corresponding to the above links in table row)

I googled it, the code uses jsZipUtil, but I cannot find the script to include in my html file src tag to use it.

I don't want to use npm install, as i wish to pass this html link to my friend and I want that the link
should work on his laptop as well without him downloading any npm stuff.

Is there any way out ? Any way will work ( with/without jsziputil )

here is my code  : Currently it gives me error that undefined reference to jsZipUtils ..

```
function urlToPromise(url) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(data);
        }
    });
  });
}

function downloadAll() {

//Create zip file object
var zip = new JSZip();

for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {      
zip.file(allFileNames[i], urlToPromise(allLinks[i]), {binary:true});
}

//Compile all the data into memory.
var base64 = null;
if (JSZip.support.uint8array) {
  promise = zip.generateAsync({type : "uint8array"});
} else {
  promise = zip.generateAsync({type : "string"});
}

//Generate the zip file and download it.
zip.generateAsync({type:"base64"}).then(function (base64) {
    location.href="data:application/zip;base64," + base64; 
});

}
```

Regards

Comment: Add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip-utils/0.1.0/jszip-utils.min.js"></script>`